# "Control Panel" V.S. "Control Cabinet"

Tags: meaning, differences

I want to know the differences between theses two terms.  For my own understanding, I think they mean the same thing but appearences are different.  Or could it mean that the control panel is usually in the control cabinet?

Comment: It may help to note that in general, a *panel* has the controls "on" it, while a cabinet "encloses" the controls. (*panel* <- *pane*: flat surface; *cabinet* <- *cabin*: small room.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an image from [Quartz TSL](http://www.quartz-tsl.com/panel_wiring_and_cubicles.htm) showing a cabinet they made:

[image: Control cabinet]

It has a door, and inside it are a number of panels containing individual controls. You can see cabling feeding the back of an additional panel which is accessible when the door is closed.

Control panel: a collection of controls
Control cabinet: a cabinet housing controls (which are probably mounted on panels)

Comment: This is a nice example , but there's no reason why a control cabinet can't have controls on the outside (this one might, even).  Size may be a factor as well, but if the user has to open a door to access the controls that tips the balance in favour of "cabinet" even if it's quite small.

Comment: @ChrisH Care to see my comment at OP?

Comment: @Kris I agree, and nice to give the etymology.  If it were an answer it would deserve a vote - this is after all question about English, not engineering terminology.

Comment: "which are probably mounted on panels": rather, it may **have** panels (sheets on all sides) -- some of which will have openings for access to the controls. Dials & switches (what the layman thinks of as 'controls' mainly) are mounted on panels, with the actual stuff enclosed safely inside the cabinet.

Comment: For heaven's sake: if people think they can do better than this answer, write one!

Answer (score 0):

The control cabinet is the complete thing - the electrical cabinet with all there is to it. 
The control panel is just the door in front of the control cabinet - when this door has buttons and/or touchscreens for operating. You could also substitute for 'operator panel'. The control panel can also be a seperate 'button' panel inside a desk or something. Use google images for clear examples of the difference between control cabinet and control panel. Good luck!